# extract the domain name from the urls in another list

Tags: python, string, list, url, text-extraction

extract the domain name from the urls in another list. Also you need to extract the ending string which the url ends with.
For example, https://www.example.com/market.php -- In this example, domain name is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and the ending string is php

```
Extract the domains and the ending string
```

```
# List of urls
url_list = ['https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/parts-url',
            'https://www.almabetter.com/enrollments',
            'https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html',
            'https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `urlparse(url)` from `urllib`! (`from urllib.parse import urlparse`):

```
parsed_url = urlparse(url)

domain = parsed_url.netloc
ending = parsed_url.path.split('.')[-1]
```

Comment: No thats not write since i am passing in list , i found the good solution.    ```domain_list = [x.split('/')[2] for x in url_list]
ending_string_list = [x.split('/')[-1].split('.')[-1] for x in url_list]```

Comment: Iterate over the list? Just make a list of urls and then `for url in urls: [...]`?